# Android text box with spinner-like dropdown

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a text box that, when the user types something, it asynchronously expands a drop-down menu that contains suggestions, much like how the Google search bar shows predictive search queries. In other words, combining an EditText with a Spinner in the sense that the user types something and it presents a list of selectable options right below it. Does such a class exist in the Android library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial from android:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

is an auto complete example on a EditText.